# ColdFusion looping through [only part] of a list

Tags: list, loops, coldfusion

Really struggling with finding a way to loop through only part (or half maybe?) of a coldfusion list. I've got an if statement set up to check the length of the list and if it is over 30... I want to split the list into the first 30 and the remainder? Not sure if that's the best solution though. I really don't need much detail I'm sure I can figure that much out myself I am more looking just to be pointed in the right direction...

Comment: Re: *"Not sure if that's the best solution.."* - Looping or splitting the list at all?

Comment: I was referring to splitting the list.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the ultimate goal or maybe open a new question?

Comment: I am pulling screen shots from the sitemaps of about eight different elaborate sites using IECapt from the command line. It works just fine if I were to grab up to about 30 screenshots by adjusting the 'delay' attribute. However, each site has around 150 different screens within itself (8 different sites). I've tried incorporating the 'cfthread' tag in my code to speed up the process but still cannot complete the task in one full run. My goal is to have reusable functions within a component to perform the action on any number of sites at one time with any number of screen shots within them.

Comment: What do you mean by "one full run"? Side note: I think you should pose this as a separate question for more exposure/feedback from a broader audience.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than looping over the list, loop from 1 to a number, and use listGetAt() in the loop.  For the remainder of the list, just loop from #myvar + 1# to #listLen#.

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#myVar#" index="idx">
        #listGetAt( myList, idx )#<br />
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Granted, it's not the most efficient method.  If you encounter performance issues, might want to convert the list to an array via listToArray(), and then do:

```
<cfset myArray = listToArray( myList ) />

<cfoutput>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#myVar#" index="idx">
        #myArray[ idx ]#<br />
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the underlying java functions.

```
<cfscript>
testList = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...,43,44";
listAsArray = listToArray(testList);
testChunk = listAsArray.subList(0,30);
</cfscript>
```

will give you an array "testChunk" with the first 30 items in the list. You can now easily loop over the elements of the Array.

To make this more clear, here is an example:

```
<cfscript>
    testList = "";
    maxChunkLength = 30;
    for (i=1;i lte 100; i=i+1){
        testList = listAppend(testList, i);
    }
    numOfChunks = ceiling(listLen(testList)/maxChunkLength);
    listAsArray = listToArray(testList);
    numOfItems = arraylen(listAsArray);
    for (k=1;k lte numOfChunks; k=k+1){
        startItem = (k - 1) * maxChunkLength;
        endItem = startItem + maxChunkLength;
        if (endItem gt numOfItems){
            endItem = numOfItems;
        } 
        writeOutput(listAsArray.subList(startItem, endItem).toString() & "<br />");
    }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. I am much more familiar with Java and just beginning ColdFusion this makes the most sense to me. I wish I could have saved you the trouble had a already known about the *subList()* method...

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on what you are trying to accomplish, how the 2 separated sets of data will be used and whst type of data you have in the list... does the data really need to be separated? can you just:

```
<cfloop from="31" to="#listLen(myList)#" index="i">
      #listGetAt(myList, i)#
</cfloop>
```

If you don't need to take the extra step of separating into 2 lists or arrays, save your self some coding & execution time

Also - if your starting point changes, you can always:

```
<cfloop from="#start#" to="#listLen(myList)#" index="i">
     #listGetAt(myList, i)#
</cfloop>
```

-sean

Comment: Yes, or I could use -
`<cfloop from="listGetAt(myList,#start#)" to="listGetAt(myList,#end#)" index="i">
</cfloop>`

Answer (score 0):

In CF10 or Railo 4, you could use the [first()](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/#first) and [rest()](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/#rest) functions from [Underscore.cfc](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/) to split up your list:

```
_ = new Underscore();

myArray = listToArray(myList);

firstThirty = _.first(myArray, 30);
remaining = _.rest(myArray, 31);
```

`_.first()` and `_.rest()` both return new arrays based on the index passed into them. The methods simply delegate to the native `arraySlice()` function, but they can help you write more expressive code.

Note: I wrote Underscore.cfc